# Parsley custom validator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

i'm trying to make a customn validator, but it doesn't working.

html:

```
<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate="">
 <a href="#" id="validateButton">
   Validate
 </a> 
 <span data-parsley-patient-is-selected></span>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

js:

```
window.parsley.addValidator('patientIsSelected', {
validateString: function() {
    return false;
},
requirementType: 'string',
messages: {
    en: 'This file should not be larger than %s Kb',
    fr: "Ce fichier est plus grand que %s Kb."
}
}); 

$('#validateButton').click(function() {
    var instance = $("#demo-form").parsley();
    instance.validate();
    var result = instance.isValid();
    $("#result").text('Validation result is ' + result);
});
```

And i'm can't find working example on stackoverflow

[See my example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frontfrend/e3yz1c73/2/)

Comment: What is there in the `form` to be validated ?

Comment: By attribute 'data-parsley-patient-is-selected' parsley shall do some logic and if result of some logic will be true then form is valid

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check the examples of [custom validators](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/customvalidator.html), which includes one for max file size.